# FindObjectOfType<> Vs GameObject.FindObjectOfType<>

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I use `FindObjectOfType<>` and `GameObject.FindObjectOfType<>` it's bringing me to the same result but I don't know what the difference is between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Quick answer

it's the same function with the same logic. But how can this be? Let me explain:

#### Object.FindObjectOfType

Docs: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html

Checking the documentation, it looks like this is a static function declared on the `Object`

```
public static T FindObjectOfType();
```

Static functions, have nothing to do with the object state of the object and can only manipulate static (shared in a sense between all objects) data.

Now, every other object in C#, inherits from the `Object` and so does the  `GameObject`. So effectively, when you are calling the `GameObject.FindObjectOfType` you are calling by inheritance the original function.

Does this make sense?